$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2}\le\left(\sqrt{\frac{A}{b}}-\sqrt{\frac{a}{B}}\right)^2$
Let $a_i,b_i (i=\overline{1,n})$ be real numbers, set $A=\max a_i, a=\min a_i, B=\max b_i, b=\min b_i$. Prove that
$$\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^2}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i}-\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i^2} \le \left(\sqrt{\frac{A}{b}}-\sqrt{\frac{a}{B}}\right)^2$$
It's my homework from school.
I tried to take inequality into SOS
$$\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(a_iS_b-b_iS_a\right)^2}{ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i \cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i^2 } \le \left(\sqrt{\frac{A}{b}}-\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{B}}\right)^2$$
where $S_a=\sum a_i,S_b=\sum b_i$ but it doesn't work. So far, i haven't got any idea. Could anyone help me with this problem? Thank you.

$a_i$ and $b_i$ are just real? Not positive? Because if they are just real, $\sum a_i b_i$ may ne zero...

What's the source of this problem?

@Ѕᴀᴀᴅ I have just edited it. Thank you.

First, note that the inequality makes sense only if $S_{ab}=\sum a_ib_i, S_b=\sum b_i^2, b, B \neq 0$ and $M=A/b, m=a/B \geqslant 0$. Let $S_a=\sum a_i^2,$ note then above $\implies S_a, m+M>0$.
We need to show
$$\frac{S_a}{S_{ab}}-\frac{S_{ab}}{S_b}\leqslant (\sqrt{M}-\sqrt{m})^2=(m+M)-2\sqrt{mM}\tag{1}$$
It is easy to see that:
$$\left(a_i-m\,b_i\right)\left(M\,b_i-a_i\right)\geqslant 0$$
$$\implies (m+M)S_{ab} \geqslant mM\,S_b+S_a \tag{summing above over $i$}$$
Also note this implies $S_{ab}> 0$ as the RHS is positive.
$$\implies \frac{S_{a}}{S_{ab}} \leqslant (m+M)-mM\frac{S_b}{S_{ab}}$$
$$\implies  \frac{S_a}{S_{ab}}-\frac{S_{ab}}{S_b}\leqslant (m+M)-mM\frac{S_b}{S_{ab}}-\frac{S_{ab}}{S_b}$$
Hence for proving $(1)$,it is enough to show
$$mM\frac{S_b}{S_{ab}}+\frac{S_{ab}}{S_b} \geqslant 2\sqrt{mM}$$
which is just AM-GM.

Thank you, very nice.
